# Excel Formula: list result of approximate match via INDEX - SMALL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been using the INDEX-SMALL-ROW array formula for a while now to pull list of matches, such as:

`=INDEX(TRACKER!$A$2:$A$100, SMALL(IF($B$3=TRACKER!$H$2:$H$100, ROW(TRACKER!$H$2:$H$100)-MIN(ROW(TRACKER!$H$2:$H$100))+1, ""), ROW($A1)))`

I just pull it down to however results I'm expecting and it works great. However I've run into a situation where I need to input multiple entries into one cell, for example the criteria column can have a cell with (apples,grapes,oranges) separated by commas; I still want it to pull even if B3  gets an input of just (grapes), or just (oranges). As long as the word/number appears in the cell, its okay to pull.

Wasn't sure how to accomplish this, would appreciate any help...thanks.

Comment: change `$B$3=TRACKER!$H$2:$H$100` to `ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$3,TRACKER!$H$2:$H$100))`

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much Scott.